# Issue with memory setting up Magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, memory

I'm trying to install Magento on my VPS (WHM/cPanel) but I get the following error. I've checked the memory and increased it to 512M but still no luck.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 248 bytes) in /home/exampleuser/public_html/vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/ResourceModel/Report/Rule/Updatedat.php on line 36
```

Things I've tried:

- Developer Mode
- Check .htaccess file
- Changed the php.ini in the root to have more memory
- Changed php.ini of the server also ..

I've never had issues with memory before, the Magento system requirements are met.

Comment: How are you trying to install? Which platform?

Comment: via GUI, tried the command line and its the same.. No extra info is given, I have enabled logging and tried it in developer mode. Why has my post have a -1 next to it?

Comment: Try via command line using: `php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento [command]`

Comment: Who is the host?

Comment: @MagePsycho That didn't do anything. It's hosted on TransIP with a WHM/cPanel setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error indicates the memory limit is 32 MB (very low). Given the ways you've already tried to override it (including through cPanel), I would recommend contacting your host about the problem.

You might also see if your host has any kind of FAQ for dealing with PHP setting changes; sometimes there are special arrangements.

Comment: You were correct, I did a find for memory_limit and found another php.ini file. Thank you for the help!